# How do you solve this recurrence relation with divides?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I am trying to find all sequences $(a_n)$ of positive integers with the following property: for all $m$ and $n$, $a_ma_n$ divides $a_{m+n}$.  I’m not sure whether this counts as a recurrence relation or not, given the presence of “divides”.

Two sequences that satisfy it are $b^n$ for any positive integer $b$, and $n!$.  But how would I find the general solution?

Comment: Define $\,b_{n,k}:=a_n/(a_ka_{n-k}).\,$ Then this is an integer **iff** it satisfies
the property you mention. The new sequence $\,b_{n,k}\,$ is an analogue of the
binomial coefficients. A nice example is [Gaussian binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any prime $p$ and $k\in \mathbb N^+$, let $\nu_p(k)$ be the largest power of $p$ dividing $k$. The divisibility condition implies $\nu_p(a_{n+m})\ge \nu_p(a_n)+\nu_p(a_m)$, so that the sequence $\nu_p(a_n)$ is super-additive in $n$ for all $p$. Clearly, this is sufficient as well.

This gives a full characterization of all sequences $a_n$ which work; they are defined by a collection of super-additive sequences $\nu_p(a_n)$ for each prime $p$, with the only constraint between the sequences being that for each $n\in\mathbb N$, $\nu_p(a_n)$ must be nonzero for only finitely many $p$.

There are several infinite classes of examples [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4034741/properties-of-sequence/4034999#4034999).

Comment: So the Fibonacci sequence is an example?

Comment: The Fibonacci factorials are an example, $d_n:=F_nF_{n-1}\cdots F_1$. That is, $a_na_m|a_{n+m}$ iff $r_1\cdots r_n|r_{m+1}\cdots r_{m+n}$, where $r_n=a_n/a_{n-1}$, and the question I linked is discussing examples of $r_n$.

Comment: So the s_n’s listed aren’t examples, instead you need to do d_n = s_n...s_1?

Comment: Exactly (I edited my last comment to clarify).